# syscp cron_traffic.php needs 10 minutes to execute

Tags: mysql, debian

I use syscp on debian and i noticed that this script is taking more than 10 minutes to execute:

```
date ; /usr/bin/php5 -q /var/www/syscp/scripts/cron_traffic.php; date

Do 5. Dez 12:09:09 CET 2013
Do 5. Dez 12:21:53 CET 2013
```

And it uses much CPU on my athlone 2300 singlecore.

What is this script doing and can I comment out some functional parts in it that I might not need to speed it up?

I started

```
/usr/bin/php5 -q /var/www/syscp/scripts/cron_traffic.php;
```

watching the debuglog ($debugHandler) in another console with

```
tail -f /var/run/syscp_cron_traffic.lock-*
```

for each syscp user it starts this block:

```
http traffic for gw started...
ftp traffic for gw started...
total traffic for gw started
calculating webspace usage for gw
calculating mailspace usage for gw
calculating mysqlspace usage for gw
```

most of them are really slow!

here you see the source of the script: https://gist.github.com/rubo77/7821112

Comment: I could take a wild stab in the dark here, and guess that maybe it has to do with some kind of traffic/log analysis.  Log analysis by its very nature is slow.

Comment: Traffic analysis often does reverse IP lookups and these can be very slow.  If it has configurable parameters, try turning that one off.  Or edit the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a solution but a **workaround**:

I changed the interval of the traffic cron to twice a month and at night (4:20 am) in:

```
/etc/cron.d/syscp
```

20 4 1,15 * *      root    /usr/bin/php5 -q /var/www/syscp/scripts/cron_traffic.php